# OpenGL texture won't map - white square?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, cairo

Alright, so I'm using cairo to turn an SVG into image data for openGL textures.

That part works.

But now the texture I'm using won't map to the quad I'm making. It's just showing up as a blank square.

Is there something up with the order I'm calling things in or is there some secret function I forgot to use?

```
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

int frame = 0;
SDL_Event event;
bool quit;
GLuint texture[1];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    g_type_init();
    rsvg_init();

    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_OPENGL );

    SDL_WM_SetCaption ("Cairo", NULL);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);

/*2D stuff - it worked here
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
*/  

//An attempt at setting up 3D stuff
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glViewport(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
glClearDepth(1.0);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
//glLoadIdentity();


    float FlowerWidth = .5;
    float FlowerHeight = .5;

    float FlowerTextureWidth = 80;
    float FlowerTextureHeight = 80;

    float FlowerScaleWidth = 1;
    float FlowerScaleHeight = 1;
    cairo_surface_t* Flower;
    cairo_t* context;

    Flower = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, FlowerTextureWidth, FlowerTextureHeight);
    context = cairo_create(Flower);

    const gchar* Filename = "resources/area/haneda/lavender.svg";
    RsvgHandle* SvgData = rsvg_handle_new_from_file(Filename, NULL);

    rsvg_handle_render_cairo_sub(SvgData, context,"#1000");
    unsigned char *buffer = cairo_image_surface_get_data(Flower);
    cairo_surface_write_to_png(Flower,"flower.png");


//Make a texture
        glGenTextures(1, &texture[1]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
    glPixelStoref(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    glGetError();
    //or am I supposed to use GL_TEXTURE_2D?
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_RGBA,
    FlowerHeight,
    FlowerWidth,
    0,
    GL_BGRA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    buffer);
//done  


    while (quit==false) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) { 
            quit = true; 
            }
            }




            /*
FlowerScaleWidth+=.001;
FlowerScaleHeight+=.001;
cairo_scale(context,FlowerScaleWidth,FlowerScaleHeight);
*/










glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);

glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glTexCoord2f (FlowerWidth, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (FlowerWidth, 0.0, 0.0);

    glTexCoord2f (FlowerWidth, FlowerHeight);
    glVertex3f (FlowerWidth, FlowerHeight, 0.0);

    glTexCoord2f (0.0, FlowerHeight);
    glVertex3f (0.0, FlowerHeight, 0.0);
glEnd ();
glDeleteTextures(1, &texture[1]);


        cairo_save (context);
        cairo_set_source_rgba (context, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        cairo_set_operator (context, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
        cairo_paint (context);
        cairo_restore (context);

        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
        //glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );   
//SDL_Delay(100);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glGetError();   


SDL_Delay(400);

        }

}
```

Comment: how is it that you can write complex cairo and opengl code and still miss glaring beginner c++ errors?  We all make them, but usually I'd double check my code for correctness before posting it online for questions.  I'm not just being mean, either you didn't try to solve this problem yourself (shame on you) or i am truly amazed.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, you've made an int array of length 1, but you pass the (non-existing) element 2 to **glGenTextures**. That reads beyond the array bounds and is *undefined behavior*. You also seem to delete the texture name inside your rendering loop. The same illegal indexing is used there too, as well in your call to **glBindTexture**.

Comment: the delete part is likely the reason for white. But the texture[1] is *really* bad. torch, C arrays are 0-indexed. so you need to write texture[0] to access the (only) element of GLuint texture[1].

Comment: ohhh. So I'm guessing that if an array only has one element, even if it's texture[5], that would have to be accesssed through texture[0]?